# "Virtual folder" in Linux

Tags: linux, web-services, filesystems

I have a web service which allows the users to upload and keep track of their files on the server. 
What I want to do is create some sort of application which recreates my "online file system" on the local machine. Kind of like having a folder on my desktop which presents the files I have on the webserver, where I can move them, open, save, etc. If you know Dropbox you get the idea of what I want to accomplish.

My problem is that I have no clue on where to start to develop this. I guess I could go for some sort of Nautilus extension, but then I would be dependent of that file manager so I think it should be something implemented directly in the OS' filesystem.

I have already figured out how to do this on Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx) and it seems pretty straight forward.

So what I want to know is if anyone here has experience in doing this on Linux and whats the best way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You basically just need a mirror of the files on the webserver?  If so, what about `rsync`—or, if it needs to be fancier, `unison`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use fuse to make a virtual file system: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), [sourceforge](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). Here's a [tutorial](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/) and another for [python](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FUSE_Python_tutorial)

It emulates a drive so it will work in the shell or nautilus or anything else.

There is also a Mac port so it could work there too.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, now I also understand the question. ;-)

Comment: Thinking of it, I’ve used `curlftpfs` once to mount a web server’s directory via FTP.  If you have SSH access, `sshfs` might be a better choice.

Comment: `curlftpfs` uses fuse, but if it makes it easier, why not ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop this by yourself, use fuse

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

But if I were in you, I would try first in searching an already existing solution with fuse, depending on the capabilities of your server.

HIH

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested, you should be able to use Fuse.

You don't specify how your web service works, but if it's WebDAV-based (which would make sense for this type of application), then you could use existing Fuse modules for WebDAV such as [davfs2](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2).

Answer (score 0):

Before you go ahead and create you own yet-another-network-filesystem I would recommend you look at what's already out there.

The first thing that comes to mind is ssh/scp/sftp. On modern unix (BSD, Solaris, Linux, MacOSX etc) the ssh daemon comes pre-installed by default. You just need to write scripts to manage user accounts from your web application.

If it HAS to be a web based thing then look at WebDAV. You can run WebDAV using most web servers. There is already a WebDAV filesystem on Linux and it looks like it is even built-in to Windows XP and above: [winnt webdav network drive](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html).

[Box.net](http://www.box.net/) is one such service using WebDAV.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.dropbox.com/